# HTML - How to pre-populate form field with known value upon load?

Tags: html

I have this web page, say Home.html, that has links to other employee-related web sites.  There is one, say www.SomeSite.com/HR.xyz, where it has a form to login.  There are 3 fields: UserId, Password, and Company.  The company is always the same, e.g. MyCo.  How can I update the Home.html page so that when the user clicks on the link to , www.SomeSite.com/HR.xyz, it automatically populates the Company field with "MyCo"?

I looked at the DOM and found the following:

`<input autocomplete='off' class='loginInput' tabindex='3' type="text" name="company" id="company" value="" maxlength='50' size="25">`

I tried the following by entering it in the URL and it did not work (no error, just didn't populated the "company" field: www.SomeSite.com/HR.xyz?company=MyCo.

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 46):

Change the `value` attribute:

```
<input autocomplete='off' class='loginInput' tabindex='3' type="text"
name="company" id="company" value="MyCo" maxlength='50' size="25">
```

Comment: I don't have access to that site, i.e. www.SomeSite.com/HR.xyz.  I have access to www.MyCo.com/Home.html.  Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks, this worked for me... such a simple thing, very nice for what I wanted +1

Comment: If this isn't working for you, there may be Javascript on the page that is resetting the value to empty.

Answer (score 8):

You could try using a get request to populate the input box in the form. That's only if the url like you said is as such www.SomeSite.com/HR.xyz?company=MyCo. In PHP you would simply include:

`<input autocomplete='off' class='loginInput' tabindex='3' type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $_GET["company"]; ?>" maxlength='50' size="25">`

As you can see that within the value attribute is a echo statement that echoes the get request in the URI where HR.xyz?**company**=MyCo contains the company get request. If you are using just pure html with no scripting language like php the only other method is by having this code:

`<input autocomplete='off' class='loginInput' tabindex='3' type="text" name="company" id="company" value="myCo" maxlength='50' size="25">`

Answer (score 2):

If your users universally use Internet Explorer, you could do something a bit hackish with VBScript, e.g.

`Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

IE.Navigate "http://www.SomeSite.com/HR.xyz"

IE.Visible = True

IE.Document.All.Item("company").Value = "MyCo"

But that would be hard to distribute to your users because they would have to click through some security errors, and it requires IE.

If they're Firefox users I would suggest looking into Mozilla Autofill.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way of reading the value passed in the URL on the HR.xyz page. You need to either use Javascript or some server side logic (PHP, .NET, etc)