# How to use Get to update php field

Tags: php, joomla

I found.
[HTML - How to pre-populate form field with known value upon load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055199/html-how-to-pre-populate-form-field-with-known-value-upon-load?newreg=ce317f9cd76942f7a8ceec43e7565877)

And tried to apply what I learnt from;

```
<input autocomplete='off' class='loginInput' tabindex='3' type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $_GET["entered"]; ?>" maxlength='50' size="25">
```

To the following piece of code ( from J-Cook Component I am constructing )

```
<?php
// incident
$field = $fieldSet['jform_incident'] ;

?>
<div class="control-group <?php echo 'field-' . $field->id . $field->responsive; ?>">
    <div class="control-label">
        <?php echo $field->label; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">

        <?php echo $field->input; ?>
```

Assuming the code would be different to the example above I tried a number of ways to make the form auto fill the

```
<?php echo $field->input; ?>
```

with out any luck. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. I am completely lost now?? :(

Thanks

Here's the whole page with the updated code provided so far..

```
    <?php
/**                               ______________________________________________
*                          o O   |                                              |
*                 (((((  o      <    Generated with Cook Self Service  V2.7     |
*                ( o o )         |______________________________________________|
* --------oOOO-----(_)-----OOOo---------------------------------- www.j-cook.pro --- +
* @version      1.02
* @package      Safety 101
* @subpackage   Incident Actions
* @copyright    2014 Jonathan Bell
* @author       JB
* @license      
*
*             .oooO  Oooo.
*             (   )  (   )
* -------------\ (----) /----------------------------------------------------------- +
*               \_)  (_/
*/

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');


if (!$this->form)
    return;

$fieldSets = $this->form->getFieldsets();
?>
<?php $fieldSet = $this->form->getFieldset('actionsitem.form');?>
<fieldset class="fieldsform form-horizontal">


    <?php
    // Person responsible
    $field = $fieldSet['jform_person_responsible'];
    $field->jdomOptions = array(
        'list' => $this->lists['fk']['person_responsible']
            );
    ?>
    <div class="control-group <?php echo 'field-' . $field->id . $field->responsive; ?>">
        <div class="control-label">
            <?php echo $field->label; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php
    // Date due
    $field = $fieldSet['jform_action_due_date'];
    ?>
    <div class="control-group <?php echo 'field-' . $field->id . $field->responsive; ?>">
        <div class="control-label">
            <?php echo $field->label; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php
    // Short description
    $field = $fieldSet['jform_action_title'];
    ?>
    <div class="control-group <?php echo 'field-' . $field->id . $field->responsive; ?>">
        <div class="control-label">
            <?php echo $field->label; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php
    // Full description
    $field = $fieldSet['jform_full_description'];
    ?>
    <div class="control-group <?php echo 'field-' . $field->id . $field->responsive; ?>">
        <div class="control-label">
            <?php echo $field->label; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php
    // Completed date
    $field = $fieldSet['jform_action_completed_date'];
    ?>
    <div class="control-group <?php echo 'field-' . $field->id . $field->responsive; ?>">
        <div class="control-label">
            <?php echo $field->label; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php
    // Action completed
    $field = $fieldSet['jform_completed_yn'];
    ?>
    <div class="control-group <?php echo 'field-' . $field->id . $field->responsive; ?>">
        <div class="control-label">
            <?php echo $field->label; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php
    // incident
$field = $fieldSet['jform_incident'] ;

?>
<div class="control-group <?php echo 'field-' . $field->id . $field->responsive; ?>">
<div class="control-label">
    <?php echo $field->label; ?>
</div>

<div class="controls">

<?php
$current_field = $field->input;
$current_field_input = str_replace('/>', '', $current_field);
$current_field_input = str_replace('>', '', $current_field);

?>
<?php echo $current_field_input; ?> autocomplete='off' value="<?php echo (isset($_GET["entered"])) ? $_GET["enter"] : ""; ?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Is `$field` an `object`? If it is an array then it should be `<?php echo $field["input"]; ?>`

Comment: Please provide us more info to help you better.

Comment: Hi, not an object. The input field works. I'm now trying to autofill the field from the url. the url has ?entered=(what ever the unix timestamp was) from the previous form. ?entered=1434618105. I'm trying to get the 1434618105 to fill the field.

Comment: I tried <?php echo $field->input autocomplete='off' value="<?php echo $_GET["entered"]; ?>"; ?> but I get the following error:   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/safereco/public_html/test/components/com_safety101/views/actionsitem/tmpl/actionsitem_form.php on line 145

Comment: What is the line 145?

Comment: It should be: `<?php echo $field->input; ?> autocomplete='off' value="<?php echo $_GET["entered"]; ?>"; ?> ` if it is the code from your last comment.

Comment: Yup it is.. I'll go chuck it in. But first I will have a look at whats different so I can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok gave it a go, What happens now is it shows the field and echo's autocomplete='off' value="1434618105"; ?> behind the field instead of filling the field.

Comment: Thanks rolfl for you help so far. really appreciate it.

Comment: @rolfl Any Ideas whats up with the code now? it shows the text autocomplete='off' value="1434618105"; ?> on the screen after the input field.

Comment: No idea from me. I maintain the JDOM Java library, which you initially tagged this question with. Since this question is neither Java, not JDOM, I removed that tag. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

JFormField classes have preset and default options built in (these are different, default is what saves if your field is left blank) which you can set in the XML (file or string) for your form. The API will also let you change attributes of the form or add new attributes.   If you use the API the whole code will be much easier to write and read.   Take a look at some examples in the core CMS and you will see many examples.
A few typical examples are below showing add, set and get:

```
$fieldset->addAttribute('description', 'COM_CATEGORIES_ITEM_ASSOCIATIONS_FIELDSET_DESC');

$field->addAttribute('edit', 'true');
$form->setFieldAttribute('ordering', 'disabled', 'true');
$fieldName = $field->getAttribute('name');
```