# Can i give the Client a form AutoFill?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser, autofill

You all know the AutoFill Feature for forms in Browser. I have the following situation: I have a WebApp and my users have to manually enter some Data which i give to them into a form on another website. 
To improve that process, i'd like to give my client something he can just paste into this form. So the question is: Can i give him an AutoFill or something to paste into said form?

EDIT: this is no duplicate! I do not need the process to be completely automatic. I just want to give the user the opportunity to achieve his goal faster, like pasting the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - How to pre-populate form field with known value upon load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055199/html-how-to-pre-populate-form-field-with-known-value-upon-load)

Comment: No duplicate, since this guy wants to do it by URL and therefore cannot use something like the Browsers AutoFill-Feature.

Comment: Did you read the answer there? If you are not filling by url and don't have access to code question becomes is there a product that does this and its off topic. how about you check chrome form filler from their app store

Comment: Yes i read the answer there... But this guy wants to do it completely automatically and that is not what i want to do. That is also the reason why this question is not duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Technically what you want is possible, the user can add javascript either by hand or using a custom plugin, but you can't do that for them, which probably means that it probably isn't suitable to achieve your desired goals.

Doing what you describe is really only feasible if the users are constrained to do what you tell them for some reason -- a scenario where what you describe would make sense and where it would be achievable, would be where you are their employer and need to automate transferring data from one system to another, but did not have control of the destination system for some reason, and there was some interaction on the destination that couldn't be totally automated on your end.

More likely, this is random users who do not have any great incentive to do things that would be potentially dangerous,  in which case, the best you can do is to create a web page with the data that is to be pasted into their web page.  At that point it's a matter of copy/paste.

Comment: Hm i can give him a button that pastes something i want. But i guess it's not possible to give him the whole form content for paste..

Comment: You can't give him a button that pastes something into a different page, without being able to control both pages, when they are on different domains.

Comment: You didn't understand me. I want a "copy" button that makes it possible for HIM to paste the information MANUALLY. (whole form @ once)

Comment: Ok, so how can i provide a button that copy's a text for pasting into multiple fields into my clients clipboard?